# Clear previous data from array

Tags: swift4

Here I created array

```
var viewArray : [UIImageView] = [UIImageView]()

func initialization() {

    let position = self.multiDArray["positions"] as! [[String:Any]]
    for i in 0...position.count {

        let userImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()

        //code
        viewArray[i].append(userImageView)
        self.canvasView.addSubview(userImageView)
    }
}
```

Here I draw images multiple time but when I want to get next images, previous images not getting removed.

Comment: you said that _"previous images not getting removed."_, so, please help me out here, because I feel being lost... but which part of your snippet should remove the existing subview in your view?

Answer (score 0):

To remove all of the views from your current view you can use:

```
for view in viewArray {
    view.removeFromSuperView()
}
```

To empty your array you can remove all of the items using:

```
viewArrary.removeAll()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!